# Converting numpy array to pure python integer to avoid integer overflow

Tags: python, numpy

I have asked this question before and being downvoted heavily. Anyway judging by the fact that noone really sees a triple downvoted question again I repost it to make clear that I am interested in the actual answer (if there is one).

Problem statement:

I am in a situation I need the arbitrary precision feature of pure python integers. At some point in my code I have a numpy array with boolean. Something like:

```
arr
```

> array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
>           True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,
>          False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
>           True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
>          False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,
>           True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
>           True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
>          False])

which I convert it to `numpy.int64` using `arr.astype(int)` to make it arithmetic.

But I used this code to convert it to an integer it overflowed (and produced negative numbers I don't want to).

Code is using this function (which is pure python and wont have any integer overflow issue by itself):

```
def bool2int(x):
    y = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        y += j<<i
    return y
```

If I run the code directly on `np.array` (converted to int or not does not matter):

```
bool2int(arr)
```

> -2393826705255337647

```
bool2int(h.astype(int))
```

> -2393826705255337647

will I need a positive integer. So, I used a list comprehension:

```
bool2int([int(x) for x in arr])
```

> 16052917368454213969

Obviously, the number represented by `arr` exceeds the capacity of fixed precision integers (i.e. 2<sup>63</sup>-1) to be able to use ti directly.

Is there any other direct way to achieve beyond list comprehension?

Edit:

For the theory of integer overflow in python I sued this [source](https://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html).

Comment: I understand why you're re-posting, but editing the original question or adding a bounty (when the time comes) would be better practise I think

Comment: @roganjosh: the overflow is not due to the conversion, but the `bool2int`, since by converting it to `int`, you get a `numpy.int64`, not a *vanilla* `int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes that's what I am telling. I want the array as list of vanilla int

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, so its a library method. I missed the point of the question then, sorry. The Boolean array distracted me.

Comment: You lose me at the point in your question where you say you have converted the array with the `astype` method but then still call `bool2int`. Why?

Comment: @timgeb my final goal is to get an integer as representation of the original array. I tried different approaches to get there. So, one of them was using `astype(int)` as middle step.

Comment: I still don't get it. How is the first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836581/converting-numpy-array-to-pure-python-integer) not answering your question?

Comment: @timgeb: because `typeof(arr.astype(int)[0])` gives a `<class 'numpy.int64'>`, not an `int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's why the comment additionally chains `.tolist()`, no? As per the documentation of `tolist` "Data items are converted to the nearest compatible Python type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `astype(int)` seems to be working fine; the following code:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([True, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, False])
test_int = test.astype(int)

print(test_int)
print(test_int.sum())
```

Returns:

```
[1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]

37
```

The overflow exception you are getting seems unlikely here so I would look again into that because maybe you had an error somewhere else.

**Edit**

If you want to get a Python type instead of a numpy object just do:

```
test.astype(int).tolist()
```

Comment: This way you just get an array with `dtype` `np.int64` so the operation are still performed in numpy (meaning possible C code)

Comment: @Eypros please answer my question. How is the first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836581/converting-numpy-array-to-pure-python-integer) not what you need? `test.astype(int).tolist()` -> list of Python ints.

Comment: @timgeb I updated my answer using your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @timgeb, yeah that seems to work. I haven't checked before. I was overwhelmed by the down-voting :(

Answer (score 2):

One way of getting native Python type elements is `.tolist()`. Note that we can do this directly on the boolean array. Your code works fine with native Python bools.

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100,)).astype(bool)
>>> x
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> bool2int(x)
-4925102932063228254
>>> bool2int(x.tolist())
774014555155191751582008547627L
```

As an added bonus it's actually faster.

```
>>> timeit(lambda:bool2int(x), number=1000)
0.24346303939819336
>>> timeit(lambda:bool2int(x.tolist()), number=1000)
0.010725975036621094
```